# Rails active record: update a list of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables: 'countries' and 'airports'. I want to set all the countries, which have at least one airport, as 'active'. This does not work:

```
  def self.activate_by_airports
    update_all('active = 1', ['country_code IN (?)', Airport.select('DISTINCT(country_code)').where(:active => 1)])
  end
```

As I understand, Airport.select(...) returns a list of Airport objects, when I need a list of country codes.

What is the right syntax in this case?

Comment: I solved it by using a map function: Airport.select('DISTINCT(country_code)').where(:active => 1).map { |airport| airport.country_code }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Airport.select('DISTINCT(country_code)').where(:active => 1).toArray` or Airport.select('DISTINCT(country_code)').where(:active => 1).all -  Rails 3 only